# How to run long calculations without hosing the event loop in clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, event-loop

### A simple (but slow) function

I'd like to take advantage of clojurescript for some declarative, functional-style programming in the browser -- for example, to be able to do lazy calculations like:

```
(def special-nums 
  (->> (iterate inc 1)
       (filter #(= (mod % 100) 0))
       (filter #(= (mod % 7001) 0))))

(time (doall (take 1 special-nums)))
```

(Note that this specific calculation isn't at all interesting to me -- it's just an example of some code that will take an unknown amount of time to return even its first result)

### Any way to bound CPU time in chunks?

Code like this feels natural for clojure, but it's ill-suited for calling in a browser environment, where it might hose the event loop and leave a web page unresponsive. Laziness doesn't help, because even the first result can take too long to return (1500 ms on my machine).

In "normal" javascript, with an imperative loop, I'd chunk the range up and use `setTimeout` to return results asynchronously, bounding the work I'm willing to do in any given chunk. (I can even bound with explicit reference to the clock -- e.g. "keep working until 20ms have elapsed, then stop and schedule another chunk.)

Is there a good way to accomplish this in clojurescript? Obviously anything is possible through js interop, but if I'm fighting the system too hard, the value of cljs feels limited.

*I'd appreciate any advice/techniques here.*

#### Note

I'm aware of web workers and I understand that throwing the computation off to another thread of execution is always possible -- but for this question, I'd like to focus on approaches that work in a single JS event loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique that inspired this answer is a [trampoline](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/trampoline) - a function that either returns the answer, or another function that returns either the answer or a function ..... (insert recursive English text here).

We can't actually use [clojure.core/trampoline](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/trampoline) here because it would tie up the JS message loop.  Instead, we can use something like the following which will "bounce" inside `js/setTimeout`.  When `f` returns a function, we call it from `setTimeout`.  When `f` returns anything else, we call `(continuation result)`.

```
(defn continue-trampoline [continuation f & args]
  (let [result-or-fn (apply f args)
        is-answer (not (fn? result-or-fn))]
    (if is-answer (continuation result-or-fn)
      (do (js/setTimeout #(continue-trampoline continuation result-or-fn) 1)
          nil))))
```

This lets us partition the problem into smaller parts that can be solved individually in less time.

To take your special-nums example, you could break it up like this:

```
(defn calculate-special-nums [n continuation]
  (letfn [(accumulate-special-nums [accumulator partitions]
           (if (empty? partitions) accumulator
             (let [part (first partitions)
                   remaining-n (- n (count accumulator))
                   acc (->> part
                            (filter #(= (mod % 100) 0))
                            (filter #(= (mod % 7001) 0))
                            (take remaining-n)
                            (into accumulator))
                   is-complete (== n (count acc))]
               (if is-complete acc
                 #(accumulate-special-nums acc (rest partitions))))))]
    (let [nums (iterate inc 1)
          partitions (partition 1000 nums)]
      (continue-trampoline continuation
                           #(accumulate-special-nums [] partitions)))))
```

So this code would calculate 10 special numbers and alert them when all ten are calculated, without starving other users of the message loop.

```
(calculate-special-nums 10 #(js/alert %))
```

The technique could probably be extended to account for milliseconds elapsed.  For your example, I can imagine using `partition-by` instead of `partition`.  Creating a function that returns true after some time has elapsed.  e.g. `(partition-by has-the-time-elapsed? nums)` instead of `(partition 1000 nums)`.

#### Other problems

As you said, even in "normal" javascript, you will have to break up the problem - clojurescript may or may not not be an exception for expensive computation.  One great thing about programming with a pure-functional paradigm is that each of the parts are independently testable.  The output is always the same for each distinct input.  Hopefully clojurescript makes even the partitioned problems easier.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring @agent-j's excellent trampoline-based approach, I decided to try a `core.async` approach for comparison.

It works pretty nicely, and it allows me to wrap an existing `find-special-numbers` function in a `by-chunk` calculator with fairly declarative syntax:

```
(ns calculate.core
  (:require
    [figwheel.client :as fw]
    [cljs.core.async :refer [chan put! <! ]])
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go-loop]]))

(enable-console-print!)

; this is the slow, dumb function -- designed to
; take a limited-size input and produce 0 or more
; results
(defn find-special-numbers [input]
  (->> input
       (filter #(= (mod % 100) 0))
       (filter #(= (mod % 7001) 0))))

(defn now [] (-> (js/Date.) .getTime))

(defn time-slice-in-ms [ms]
  (let [start (now)]
    (fn [] (-> (now) (- start) (quot ms)))))

; run a single chunk, report results, and schedule
; the next chunk of work in the event loop.
(defn by-chunk-step [chunks calc-fn result-chan]
  (doseq [r (calc-fn (first chunks))]
    (put! result-chan r))
  (js/setTimeout #(by-chunk-step (rest chunks) calc-fn result-chan)))

; transform a set of inputs into chunks, then run
; kick off job to run a calculation function on each chunk.
; meanwhile, immediately return a result-reporting channel.
(defn by-chunk [inputs [ms] calc-fn]
  (let [result-chan (chan)
        chunks (partition-by (time-slice-in-ms ms) inputs)]
    (by-chunk-step chunks calc-fn result-chan)
    result-chan))

(defn all-ints [] #(iterate inc 1))

(defn load []
  (let [results (by-chunk (all-ints) [20 :ms] find-special-numbers)]
    (go-loop []
             (println (<! results))
             (recur))))

(fw/watch-and-reload :jsload-callback (load))
```

Note one gotcha in defining `all-ints`: it's important not to retain the head of this list, otherwise stack usage grows without bound and the browser will crash. Hence `all-ints` returns a function rather than a lazy list directly.